# Silverlight chaining multiple async web requests crashes when calling service call twice

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, chaining

Help !!

I am chaining multiple web services and when I call it once it works. the second time I tried to call the same call the eninvoke of one of the services crashes !! I have tried everything and done tons of research and have not found a solution and we have a serious deadline coming up. Here is my code ..

```
      public void RejectViolation(ViolationPage currentPage, Violation currentViolation, RejectionReason rejectionReason)
        {
            //Copy the properties over
            CurrentViolation = currentViolation;
            MyViolationPage = currentPage;
            _rejectionReason = rejectionReason;

            //First call
            ServiceAgent.Validate(CurrentViolation,
                (s, e) =>
                {
                        //Reject the violation
                        Reject();
                                   });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rejects the violation
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Nothing</returns>
        private void Reject()
        {
            //Second call
            ServiceAgent.RejectViolation(CurrentViolation,
                (s, e) =>
                {
                                                                    MyViolationPage.RemoveCurrentViolation();
                });
        }

        I am using the MVVM pattern so this is my view model. My Service Agent looks like this.

/// <summary>
        /// Validates the reject
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="violation">The violation to reject</param>
        /// <param name="callback">The callback function</param>
        public void Validate(Violation violation, EventHandler<ValidateRejectCompletedEventArgs> callback)
        {
            try
            {
                // Submit violation for Accept to server
                _client.ValidateRejectCompleted -= callback;
                _client.ValidateRejectCompleted += callback;
                _client.ValidateRejectAsync(violation);
            }
            catch (FaultException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException endpointNotFoundException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.EndpointNotFoundExceptionMessage, endpointNotFoundException);
            }
            catch (ProtocolException protocolException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.ProtocolExceptionMessage, protocolException);
            }
            catch (CommunicationException communicationException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.CommunicationExceptionMessage, communicationException);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Process the reject of a violation by a user
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="violation">
        /// Violation to be rejected
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="callback">
        /// Function callback to notify requester about result of the execution.
        /// </param>
        public void RejectViolation(Violation violation, EventHandler<RejectViolationCompletedEventArgs> callback)
        {
            try
            {
                // Submit violation for Accept to server
                this._client.RejectViolationCompleted -= callback;
                this._client.RejectViolationCompleted += callback;
                this._client.RejectViolationAsync(violation);
            }
            catch (FaultException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException endpointNotFoundException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.EndpointNotFoundExceptionMessage, endpointNotFoundException);
            }
            catch (ProtocolException protocolException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.ProtocolExceptionMessage, protocolException);
            }
            catch (CommunicationException communicationException)
            {
                throw new Exception(DataSourceMessages.CommunicationExceptionMessage, communicationException);
            }
        }
```

Is there something that I need to clean up after I do all this work ?
It works fine the first time around I call it again and it dies on the EndInvoke method
when returning a result set.

This is where it crashes the second time around

```
public CoE.VCS.SL.ViolationService.Violation EndRejectViolation(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                CoE.VCS.SL.ViolationService.Violation _result = ((CoE.VCS.SL.ViolationService.Violation)(base.EndInvoke("RejectViolation", _args, result)));
                return _result;
            }
```

it crashes while retrieving the result any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Since the Service Agent was static the callback event handlers kept accumulating. I re-instantiated the service agent on every call and it fixed the problem.